# C# List or array techniques to save memory occupation

Tags: c#, arrays, list, memory-management, arraylist

So I have a simulation I run that has 3 lists of about 200k objects. Each object holds information about a point(x,y,z) and contains an array of x objects.

Depending on the amount of frames (of the animation) in the simulation, each Point object holds an array of say 64 values.

The whole simulation takes up about 11 gigabytes of RAM. This is too much for a lot of our users. Therefore i would like to know if there are smart ways to save memory usage in this case.

At least 60% of the arrays within these points hold the value 0. I have thought of ways to use lists as pointers so that the same value (for example 0) doesn't get saved in memory a few million times, like I would in C++. However I cannot come up with an implementation for this in C#.

Any tips or tricks to reduce the 11 gigabytes of RAM the simulation occupies are well appreciated!

The Point object as described above is:

```
public class Vertex { 
    public Point3D position; 
    public float[] delta; 
}
```

There is also 3 meshes. Those hold the objects in:

```
public List<Vertex> Vertices;
```

The way the arrays are filled is with another list of points, roughly aligned with the mesh, but not exactly with each vertex, the position of these points change every frame, so each frame, each point has to assign a fraction of its value to each of the nearby vertices. So filling the vertices is not as straight forward as it looks.

I currently approached this by initializing the array with a size of e.g. 64. And then depending on whether there are any close points, a value (or an average of multiple) is assigned to the position of the current frame in that array.
Using the approach of @kookiz might be possible but will be harder than it looks on the surface.

Comment: please share code of your structures

Comment: Can you show us the code used to define your data structure?  What values will your arrays hold?  In any case you can likely get some benefit by asking the garbage collector to tidy up more often if you are creating and destroying objects frequently.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a list of points, and each point has an array storing the delta for each frame? One solution could be to rethink your whole data structure: rather than thinking per vertex, think per frame, and stream them from the disk. Of course, it's only if the calculation time for one frame is big enough that it won't be slowed down by the next one being loaded from the disk

Comment: @Satchmode edit your question and add your code there please

Comment: (continued from my previous comment): one advantage of thinking per frame rather than per vertex is that, for each frame after the first one, you can store only the information for vertexes that has changed, thus reducing the data volume per 60% (given your estimation). That's how MPEG videos are encoded.

Comment: @KooKiz Very clever way, to zoom out and dont think so specific! I've noted this and will look to implement this!